# Magento 2 How to correctly change style in less

Tags: magento-2.1, less-css, custom-theme, styles

[image: Example]

I creat my theme, same as luma, parent Blank.

I try change style for search (add `background-color` and `change opticaly`.
I see in less file: `app\design\frontend\Vendor\default\Magento_CatalogSearch\web\css\source\_module.less` only this code (need make changes here):

```
.action.search {
    display: inline-block;
    .lib-button-icon(
    @_icon-font-content: @icon-search,
    @_icon-font-size: 24px,
    @_icon-font-text-hide: true,
    @_icon-font-color: @header-icons-color,
    @_icon-font-color-hover: @header-icons-color-hover,
    @_icon-font-line-height: 24px
    );
    .lib-button-reset();
    position: absolute;
    right: @indent__s;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
```

I found `.lib-button-reset();` on `magento\lib\web\css\source\lib\_buttons.less`

```
.lib-button-reset() {
    background-image: none; // Reset unusual Firefox-on-Android default style
    background: none; // >>> Need change <<<
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box; // Hack: fix Firefox button line-height problem
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    .lib-css(font-weight, @font-weight__regular);

    &:focus,
    &:active {
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }

    &:hover {
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }

    &.disabled,
    &[disabled],
    fieldset[disabled] & {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none; // Disabling of clicks
        .lib-css(opacity, @button__disabled__opacity); // >>> Need change <<<
        // >>> Need add z-index: -1; <<<
    }
}
```

So, to correctly add `background`, change `opticaly` and add `z-index` in `app\design\frontend\Vendor\default\Magento_CatalogSearch\web\css\source\_module.less`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are using a theme or a module where you need this change made, so i will assume that you need this in a theme as it's a little more straight forward. You want to make a file in your theme here:
`app/design/frontend/{{vendor_namespace}}/{{theme_name}}/web/css/source/_extend.less`
The code you are looking for is:

```
.block-search .action.search {
  .lib-button(
    @_button-background: tomato;
  );
}

.block-search .action.search[disabled] {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This will change the background color and set the disabled state to a full opacity. This button is greyed out by default until there is text is in the search. This is to prevent people from searching a null value. But this code will override that appearance. As you will see, the background for this element will change the layout a bit, as the button was not designed to have one, but you can play with the values till you get the right results.

[image]

For more info on the ui library, you can read here:

http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/buttons.html

Comment: Thank you! But I wrote that I'm making a change in the module Magento_CatalogSearch. Use _extend.less not good when need make a lot changes. In the end, you will have many sets of css for the same blocks. Correctly need make changes in module.

Comment: Your module should have its own namespace. Are you editing the core code? If so you can just make a module with the overrides in your own dir in the app/code folder. When you do, you will just have to rename the file to `_module.less` in the `view/web/css/source` folder.